# configuring gcc compiler options in netbeans

Tags: gcc, netbeans, compiler-construction, ubuntu-10.04, netbeans-6.9

i am using [minixml](http://www.minixml.org/) library in my gcc base project. I can successfully compile the files using the following command line option

```
gcc -o <output file> <c file path> -L. -lem_log -lmxml -pthread
```

how can i compile the program with the same options in Netbeans 6.9.0 ?

Abdul khaliq

Comment: Netbeans should have an option to specify compiler options. Have you checked it?

Answer (score 0):

I know that does not exactly answer your question, however if you are using QT project in netbeans, then you could add compilation flags in project->properties->qt->expert->custom definitions, and there you could add a line smthing like : QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+=-msse3. Linking flags I'd try to add with QMAKE_LFLAGS most probably (although never tried). Again, this does not directly answer your question, but might give you some clues and work arounds..